# fetch webpage source after the webpage run Javascript - Java

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to fetch the webpage source and I found some problem. I want to get the Url on the source, but when I fetch down, the Url become a `Javascript` method.

On brower source viewer:

```
<a class="title" href="/hkstp_web/en/Directory/Acquest%20Stem%20Cell%20Research%20Company%20Limited/">aaa Company Limited</a>
```

But When I fatch it down, it become this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>...</span></a>
```

Here is my code:

```
public class DownloadPage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URL url;

        try {
            // get URL content
            url = new URL("https://www.hkstp.org/hkstp_web/en/directory/");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            //save to this filename
            String fileName = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\server\\test.txt";
            File file = new File(fileName);

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            //use FileWriter to write file
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                bw.write(inputLine + "\n");
            }

            bw.close();
            br.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

How do I get that correct link? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's different link because when you check source code viewer you see the page that was send from the server not the one that is generated by javascript.

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: Forgot to put the code.. sorry

Comment: did u get any solution for this i am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you (hopefully) know, the web pages have evolved a lot since [Sir Timothy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee) invented them. This means that what you see (an can interact with) is not just the result of the HTML (and CSS) code passed from the server, but is often heavily "post" processed by the browser using JavaScript.

So if you want to get that link, you have to do the same post-processing, i.e. using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) framework, or - if you don't insist on Java - [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).